# How to get the content of a Tinymce textarea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tinymce

i have an array of content then how we get content of Tinymce textarea in javascript

Comment: As of lately and in the latest releases, simply calling getContent will return an error everytime. The answer to your problem will be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475325/tinymce-get-content#35598975

Answer (score 34, accepted):

lets say your mce textarea instance is:

```
<textarea id="editor1" ....></textarea>
```

then you get the content as follows:

```
var content =  tinyMCE.getContent('editor1');
```

if you mean you have multiple instances of mce editor on one page and you want to get content then try this approach:

```
var inst, contents = new Object();
for (inst in tinyMCE.editors) {
    if (tinyMCE.editors[inst].getContent)
        contents[inst] = tinyMCE.editors[inst].getContent();
}
```

the above code adds each editor content into an array

Comment: This answer is most likely for an old version of TinyMCE. To do this with the latest (4.x), @jqpress's answer is the right one.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: tinyMCE.getContent is not a function

Answer (score 86):

I solved it with code:

```
// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

// Get the raw contents of the currently active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});

// Get content of a specific editor:
tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent()
```

the activeEditor is current editor,but i use tinyMCE.get('editor1').getContent() can not get the value of my editor, hope it can help you

Tinymce API:  http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

Comment: use `tinymce` instead of `tinyMCE` if version >= 4.5

Comment: @Mitoxys this still appears to fail for version >= 5

Comment: @Mitoxys oh never mind... this is weird, but `tinymce` has these properties before I call `init`, but afterwards it appears to reference an element without these properties.

Comment: **Just tested on V5**.
Use `tinymce` (no caps) and it works fine. [More info here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent).

Comment: It dosen't work: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContent' of null`. Setted my id text area in the `.get('mytextarea')`. Still dosen't work

Comment: `{format : 'raw'}` solves the issue where for example colored text is not being fetched from editor.

Comment: getContent really doesn't work as of latest releases. I believe 2020 and up.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem. I have solved using this code:

```
tinyMCE.get('editor1').getContent();
```

Source: [spocke is the author](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=9762)

Answer (score 19):

You may use:

```
tinymce.get(editorid).getContent();
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case (v4.3.12), none of the above worked, so I did a workaround:

Html code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <textarea id="editable_container" name="editable_container"></textarea>
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
var iframe = $('#editable_container_ifr');
var editorContent = $('#tinymce[data-id="editable_container"]', iframe.contents()).html();
console.log(editorContent);
```

Where `editable_container` is my tinyMCE editor's placeholder textarea, the editable area's iframe id is generated from adding a `_ifr` postfix to the placeholder's id, and the `content-editable` container (which contains the formatted text),  has an id `tinymce` with a `data-id` attribute of the placeholder's id.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getContent()` method from the TinyMCE API.

Let’s say you have initialized the editor on a textarea with id=”myTextarea”. First access the editor using that same id, then call `getContent()`. For example:

`var myContent = tinymce.get('myTextarea').getContent();`

Or, instead of accessing the editor by id, you can access the *active editor*:

`var myContent = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();`

If want to get the TinyMCE content without the HTML tags, you can pass in a parameter to indicate that you want the result in plaintext. For example:

`var myContent = tinymce.get('myTextarea').getContent({format: 'text'});`

More info and examples here: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-content-and-set-content-in-tinymce.

Comment: What options are available other than *{format: 'text'}* or *{format : 'raw'}* that another answer suggests? The [doc](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-content-and-set-content-in-tinymce/) is not very helpful as it only states there is a format:text option.

Comment: When I look into the *tinymce.js* of the DEV build, I see *tree* is a third option.

Answer (score 0):

```
tinymce.get('editorId').setContent(response.data);
```

Comment: Please include an explanation

Answer (score 0):

This work for me for version 4 (9.8):

```
var Content = tinyMCE.editors['Your_ID'].getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

For version 4.1.9, this is what worked for me:

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(() => {
    const out3 = tinyMCE.get('bobt').getContent(); //*MUST* be an ID, not a class
    alert(out3);
    $('#out').html(out3);
  });
});
```

```html
<textarea id="bobt" class="tinymce"></textarea>
<div id="outx"><button>Get it</button></div>
<div id="out"></div>
```

##### Notes:

1. `.get()` requires an ID, not a class
2. `tinymce.get()` or `tinyMCE.get()` both work -- uppercasing the `MCE` does not matter

Answer (score -3):

If you are more familiar with (and are using the jquery wrapper), you can also do this using this:

```
$('#editor1').tinymce().getContent();
```

Where (editor1) is your selector.