# Plain Text Email Message Or HTML

Tags: html, tinymce

Please consider the email editor I'm using which is as follows:

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

My Questions is, if I just type the text inside the editor, will it be considered as a plain text email or HTML email because, even if I see the Tools-> Source code option, I would be getting the source code in HTML form.

If not Plain Text, is there any way of generating Plain Text option in this case?

Please suggest. 
Thanks

Comment: An email is considered to be HTML or Plaintext based on the mime-type included in the email, not on the content returned by your editor. It's possible for text with no HTML tags to be delivered as an HTML email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i am understanding your question properly, you want to get only the text content out of the  tinymce editor.

Well if thats the case why not use a plain text area/input/content editable div ?

well you get the content of your editor in this fashion

1.[how we get content of tiny mce textarea in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551834/how-we-get-content-of-tiny-mce-textarea-in-javascript)

2.Now you might want to strip down the html tags that are associated to the content like this below
[jQuery remove tag from HTML-String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109946/jquery-remove-tag-from-html-string)

hope this helps

Comment: Actually I want to have both the functionality so that a user can switch to either Plain Text or HTML whenever he wants. Please let me know if I can provide more clarifications. Thanks

Comment: This should work for you. in case you want to get the HTML content step one should be fine otherwise step two. imagine having a flag on your UI for you to achieve your requirement