# Problems retriving the data from tinymce textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, textarea

I asked a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551834/how-we-get-content-of-tiny-mce-textarea-in-javascript) and attempted to follow the solution suggested,

```js
tinyMCE.get('.content').getContent();
```

but still won't retrive my data. now I have quadruple-checked my script for unwanted or misplaced charaters but all seems alright.  here is my code:

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".content"
 });

var  content = $('.content').val();

if(checkReady == true){
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "postproject.php",
     data: {  content: content  }
   })
     .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Information, \r\n" + msg );
     });
  }
```

Can anyone help me to find my lost content?

Comment: Could you please provide a link in the question to the other topic you mention...

Comment: Could not find it when searching for it again, but as mentioned, the answer there was to use this content = tinyMCE.get('.content').getContent();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551834/how-we-get-content-of-tiny-mce-textarea-in-javascript

Comment: Edited to actually reference the prior question.

Comment: I did not ask that question but ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling tinymce.get you need to pass the tinymce editor id as paramter.
That editor id equaly the source id of the editor element - but if there is none 'content' will be used by default.

So all you need to do is to call

```
tinymce.get('content').getContent();
```

---

**In case this does not work** you will need to find out what editor id(s) your editor(s) has/have using the following (browser console suffices):

```
for (x in tinymce.editors)
{
    console.log('Editor id:', tinymce.editors[x].id);
}
```

Now try the first piece of code and use the proper editor id(s).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will start using log feature more often seems very handy!