# Tinymce get content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I try to get the content of tinymce, like this:

```
 var hallo = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
            alert(hallo);
```

but every time I get this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContent' of null
```

I am using tinymce 4.

Thank you

Comment: Did you assign a `textarea` with a `class` and declare that with `editor_selector`?

Comment: Thank you for your answare. What do you mean?

Comment: I just set this up for you. Check the link to see what I mean. ---> http://fiddle.tinymce.com/WSeaab/1

Comment: Did it help and solve you problem?

Comment: For this yes. But I put a other post to disable/enable button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'getContent' of null` often means that `TinyMCE` is unable to find your textbox which means there is something wrong in the reference to textarea's `class`.

```
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea id="myTextArea" class="mceEditor">I should buy a boat. </textarea>
</form>

<button onclick="content()">Get content</button>
```

Take note of `mceEditor` class which we will now inform the `TinyMCE` editor about :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "mceEditor"   //<<<---- 
    });

</script>
```

And now simply get the contents of that textbox on the button click.

```
function content() {
    alert(tinyMCE.get('myTextArea').getContent());
}
```

Here is working **[DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/WSeaab/2)**

Answer (score 8):

You can get tinyMCE content by calling the the method [triggerSave](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.triggerSave) in the following way

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

after declaring this method you can get the contents by selector for example:-

```
var contents = $("#myTextArea").val();
```

or

```
var contents = tinyMCE.get('myTextArea').getContent();
```

Comment: ?? What is this??  I already marked an answare as solution. I did that in July 2015!!! it is now 2016?? Realy

Comment: It was not working to my side, If you clearly see the solution It is different from the accepted one. I do it at a site and share for others help If anyone get help from It, I would be happy.

Comment: ?? "It was not working to my side"?? You mean at your site?? You mean your website??

Comment: Yes, I mean the website on which I am working, where I need to get contents. hope you understand it now.

Comment: triggerSave isnt saving and `var contents = tinyMCE.get('myTextArea').getContent();` gets null, dont work for tinymce 4.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Shabaz's answer...

For TinyMCE version 4.1.9, I discovered the following:

1. `tinyMCE.get('bobt').getContent();`  and `tinymce.get('bobt').getContent();`  BOTH WORK *(that is, uppercase the `MCE` does not matter)*
2. `bobt` in my example code is an ID, not a class
3. The `triggerSave()` call is unnecessary - all that is important is for the textarea to have an ID, and to use the ID in the `get('#YOUR_ID').getContent()` call.

Full Example Code (non run-able):

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(() => {
    //tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    const out3 = tinyMCE.get('bobt').getContent(); //*MUST* be an ID, not a class
    alert(out3);
    $('#out').html(out3);
  });
});
```

```html
    <textarea id="bobt" class="tinymce"></textarea>
    <div id="outx"><button>Get it</button></div>
    <div id="out"></div>
```