# trouble in getting Rich text formatted document from tinymce plugin which i have used in my form

Tags: php, forms, formatting, tinymce

> I am using a TinyMCE plugin inside my form.so that user can write a small 
>     formatted blog about their job.but there is a trouble in

1. storing those data in a var using javascript.
2. processing and
3. transferring that file(.rtf) through a mail using PHP mail().

> when the user submits the form.
>
> so I need some suggestions. how I can do this thing for form.
>   so far I have tried retrieving the text using jquery but it's not working.
>   just have a look at my simplest code for retrieving those text.

```
<form>
<textarea id="tinymce"></textarea>
</form>
<button onclick="myfunctionforTinyMce()">hit me!</button>

<script>
function myfunctionforTinyMce(){
  alert($("#tinymce").val());
 }
</script>`
```

[this is the output on clicking on that button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSgbD.png)

Thank you.

Comment: the main thing in this question is i want to pass that formatted files mail() in php in formatted way not in plain text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551834/how-to-get-the-content-of-a-tinymce-textarea-with-javascript), you can see that the TinyMCE editor is not a normal TextArea. You need to call the TinyMCE object API methods for manipulating its content.

```
var content = tinymce.getContent('tinymce');
alert(content);
```

This should do the trick for your example. It will return the content in HTML format.

### EDIT

---

To get the content as plain text, try the following:

```
var content = tinymce.get('tinymce').getContent({format:'text'})
```

### EDIT #2

---

I added a CodePen below demonstrating a simple implementation with a button alerting the content to you. Just replace the alert with an AJAX-call ($.post(...) for example), or do a normal form submission where you post the content to your backend PHP server. Then let the server use the data to send the mail.

https://codepen.io/canis1980/pen/qYVKPW

Comment: i mean when we retrieve them does the format remains same or it gets  transferred to plain text?

Comment: That text is default html formatted if I remember correctly.

Comment: @RahulGupta I edited my answer to allow for getting the text as plain text.

Comment: i tried both the ways to give alert message but using this code `var content = tinymce.getContent('tinymce');
alert(content);` alert is not poping up on submitting only page get refresh. just help me in one thing. that how can i store that blog in formatted way and how can i transfer is using mail() in php.

Comment: @RahulGupta pardon my late reply, I had other things needing my attention. See my edited reply above.

Comment: your answer really helped me a lot.just suet me how an i share that `var content` with php                                                                         1. by storing var in cookie? or                                                                      2. in session which one will be better?

Comment: this is last question i am no able to make a cookie of that `var content`. **below is my code about my jquery** `<script> $(()=>{
  tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });
  $("#submit2").on("click",()=>{
   var content2 = tinymce.get('tinymce2').getContent({format:'text'});
      document.cookie="main_physical_address="+content2+"; expires=Wed, 9 May 2018 10:21:00 UTC; path=/";
  });
});
</script>` plzzz help me out in creating a cookie of that var.so thati can share that var with **php** to send that **blog text** through **mail** thank you.

Comment: @RahulGupta I updated the codepen to submit to backend.

Comment: thnx man you i got a way to make a cookie and to share it but you helped me a lot thanks again.

Comment: @RahulGupta I'm glad I could help! I hope you have everything you need now to move forward with your project.

 PS! Please remember to upvote helpful answers and accept the answer you end up using.