# How to get the value of wp_editor()'s textarea

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, wp-editor

So i am trying to have a custom textarea where users can do things like **bold text**, add ul's,link tags and so on. For all of this I am using the **wp_editor()** function inside wordpress, like this.

```
 $content = "";
 $editor_id = "e_id";
 $editor_settings = array(
                         'teeny' => true,
                         'editor_height' => 160,
                         'quicktags' => array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,del,close' ),
                         'media_buttons' => false );

 wp_editor( $content, $editor_id ,$editor_settings );
```

So everything such as adding links bolding text and so on works just fine.

My issue is accessing the text that was just typed into this field. 
I tried accessing the text using JQuery, by alerting the value of the textarea/contenteditable area like so...

```
  alert($("#e_id").val());
```

but each time the result is always an empty string and not the newly typed text.

How do I get a hold of the newly typed text

Comment: Are you using the `wp_editor()` function on the front-end?

Comment: Yes. I am attempting to generate a editor on the front-end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So while looking around on here I found a similar question related to the Wordpress wp_editor() function. [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134991/wp-editor-is-empty-on-first-submit)

Apparently there is a special tinyMce function used to access wp_editor() or the tinyMce editor's text/content.

So using this inside inside my onSubmit handler:

```
 tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()
```

I was able to get content or text that was entered into the wp_editor().

Also [another good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551834/how-to-get-the-content-of-a-tinymce-textarea-with-javascript) on the subject.