# How to keep the text format same from in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce-3

I am inserting some text using textarea. I want to substring the textarea once it reaches the limit and set the content to the same editor. But its removing the formatting before whatever is texted and setting plain text.
I want with same format.

```js
   tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        editor_selector: "mceEditor",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: 'true',
        theme_advanced_disable: 'justifyleft,justifyright,justifyfull,justifycenter,indent,image,anchor,sub,sup,unlink,outdent,help,removeformat,link,fontselect,hr,styleselect,formatselect,charmap,separator,code,visualaid,strikethrough,fullscreen',
        theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold,italic,underline,numlist,bullist,undo,redo,cleanup,spellchecker',
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
        plugins: 'spellchecker,fullscreen,paste',
        spellchecker_languages: '+English=en-us',
        spellchecker_rpc_url: '<%out.print(request.getContextPath());%>/jazzy-spellchecker',
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_path: false,
        statusbar: true,
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.onKeyUp.add(function (evt) {
                var inputRichTextArea = $(editor.getBody()).text();
                var maxLengthRichTextArea = document.getElementById(editor.id).maxLength;
                var inputRichTextAreaLength = inputRichTextArea.length;
                if (inputRichTextAreaLength > maxLengthRichTextArea) {
                    inputRichTextAreaLength = maxLengthRichTextArea;
                    editor.setContent("");
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(inputRichTextArea.substring(0, maxLengthRichTextArea));
                }
                var value = maxLengthRichTextArea - inputRichTextAreaLength;
                if (value >= 0) {
                    $(editor.getContainer()).find("#" + editor.id + "_path_row").html("Remaining characters: " + (value));
                }
                if (inputRichTextAreaLength >= maxLengthRichTextArea) {
                    $(editor.getBody()).keypress(function (e) {
                        inputRichTextAreaLength = $(editor.getBody()).text().length;
                        if (inputRichTextAreaLength >= maxLengthRichTextArea) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            return false;
                        }
                        var value = maxLengthRichTextArea - inputRichTextAreaLength;
                        if (value >= 0) {
                            $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContainer()).find("#" + editor.id + "_path_row").html("Remaining characters: " + (value));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

```html
<textarea maxlength = 50 rows="4" cols="50"></textarea
```

How can I keep the same formatting.

[Pasting text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ4pB.png)

[Formatting text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDvNq.png)

Comment: Hello, please format your code in order to work correctly and explain a bit more what you're willing to achieve.

Comment: @Felix Did format changes and inlcuded more source

Comment: please console.log(inputRichTextArea) - is this only text or the complete content as you assign it with .text() - should be .getContent() ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you use the function `.text()` to get the content which only selects the text without format. Try using `.getContent()` instead, as it selects the whole content.

There are already question and answers about it here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551834/how-to-get-the-content-of-a-tinymce-textarea-with-javascript). Please follow the instructions there.