# AJAX POST of tinyMCE contents - Character encoding of table entities

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, character-encoding

I'm using the tinyMCE editor plugin in my webpage.

When I use a simple HTML page post to post the contents to the backend PHP and save them to a database or file, all seems OK.

When I try to do the same using an AJAX post, I am finding it impossible to prevent encoding issues.

In particular (I'll escape it here) \&\n\b\s\p\; is being converted to Â and a "-" character is being converted to ï¿½

I've tried a few suggestions but with little luck.
The suggestion is that it is either an issue with my charset or encoding.
My save function is as follows:

```
function letterSave(newfile,fname){

    var newDate = new Date;
    var uniq=newDate.getTime(); 
    var input = $('#myTextareastdletter');
    var contents=input.val();
    var context='<?=(!strcmp($sessobj->mode,"SA_ViewAbs")?"A":"S");?>';
//  alert(fname);
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",       
        url: '<?=auto_version("./SVajaxSaveDocContents.php")?>?duff='+uniq,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        data: {'S_sessid' : '<?=$sessobj->sessionid?>', 'context' : context, 'contents' : encodeURIComponent(contents), 'fname' : fname, 'newfile' : newfile},      
        success: function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            fname=data[0];
            newLetterList=data[1];
            if (fname != 'FAIL') {
                alert ('OK: Letter Contents Saved to File ('+fname+').');
                var versionOutput = $('#popupOutput');
                versionOutput.html('');
                var box = $('#popupDisplay');
                var cover=$('#coverDiv');
                box.css({
                   display:"none"
                });
                cover.css({
                   display:"none"
                });
                var letterOutput = $('#AbsenceLetters');
                letterOutput.html(newLetterList);
            } else {
                alert ('Sorry: Failed to Save Letter Contents!');
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert ('Sorry: Failed to Save Letter Contents!');
//                  console.log(data);
//                  console.log('error');
        }
    });

}
```

As you can see, I've been playing with setting the contentType and using encodeURIComponent().

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Where are you initializing your tinyMCE instance? Also, is `$('#myTextareastdletter')` your textarea that is assigned to the tinymce instance?

Comment: @silencedogood The editor is displayed in a floating div. This is populated using another piece of javascript. I use the standard method calling tinymce.init.

Comment: *** I should say, I use exactly the same method to display the same editor in another page for maintaining the letter template. The only difference is that I use a standard html form/page post to save the content. This does not cause the encoding problem. It seems to only be when I use AJAX to do the post.

Comment: Yes, $('#myTextareastdletter') is the textarea where the tinyMCE is implemented. Cheers.

Comment: When I add a bit of code to write the file_put_contents to a file to the  SVajaxSaveDocContents.php script, the resulting file shows the encoding problem. The script actually saves it to database blob.

Comment: Instead of utilizing `.val` to get the value of the content in the text area, try utilizing tinyMCE's built-in `.getContent` method. I use `getContent` in my ajax posts without any encoding issues. You can read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551834/how-to-get-the-content-of-a-tinymce-textarea-with-javascript  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Worth a try, thanks. Have used it elsewhere in a different context (not alax). Tbh I used the .val as a cut and paste job from a similar function not using tinymce. Will get back. Cheers

Comment: Well yes, that did work, thanks @silencedogood. Still some encoding issues but I think they are inherited charset issues due to the text being copied into the tinymce textarea from a Word doc. I'll guide the users to check for those.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad this helped. I placed the solution in an answer if you'd be so kind as to mark is as the correct solution  :)

Comment: Was going to suggest that

Comment: Cool thanks! I already posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid these encoding issues, don't use `.val` on the `textarea` that the tinyMCE instance is attached to. Instead, you can utilize tinyMCE's built-in `getContent` method like so:

```
tinyMCEInstance.getContent()
```